# Adding context_menu items dinamically with custom functions

Tags: vb.net

I create context menu dinamically and want to assign menuitems to my own functions (with arguments). Unfortunatelly that dont go as I would like.

Following example illustrates what I would like to do.

```
Private Sub dgv_sub_CellMouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgv_sub.CellMouseUp

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        dgv_sub.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = True
        context_sub.Items.Clear()
        context_sub.Items.Add("Delete row " + dgv_sub.CurrentRow.Index.ToString, Nothing) AddressOf delRow(dgv_sub.CurrentRow.Index))
        context_sub.Items.Add("Delete all rows", Nothing) , AddressOf delRow(-1))
        context_sub.Show(New Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub delRow(ByVal rowtodelete As Integer)

End Sub
```

How to make this properly and get it to work as described?

Comment: you are quite close however i'm not sure if you really need this to be dynamic. you can add the two items before and add a click event, then in `MouseDown` set the visibility is you want. Let me know if this does not help

Comment: Hi Keith. Here are other non described functions which have to be dinamically since situation under this context menu may be much different. For this example I show simplified version enough to describe my needs.

Comment: Ok I get it, I will post my answer in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I usually do these kind of things:

1. Have a pre populated `ContextMenu`
2. Assign the `ContextMenu` to my `DataGridView`
3. Add Events on every `ToolStripMenuItem`
4. In each event, first I do a check to make sure that a row has been selected

`If dgv_sub.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then`

then, I get the correct row by using the

`SelectedRows(0)`

5. To make things neater, you can also use the `DataGridView.MouseDown` event to make sure that when the user right click a row, it gets selected.

   ```
   Private Sub dgv_sub_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles dgv_sub.MouseDown
       If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
           Dim hitTest As DataGridView.HitTestInfo
           hitTest = dgv_sub.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

           If hitTest IsNot Nothing AndAlso hitTest.RowIndex > -1 Then
               dgv_sub.CurrentCell = dgv_sub.Item(hitTest.ColumnIndex, hitTest.RowIndex)
               dgv_sub.Rows(hitTest.RowIndex).Selected = True
           End If
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

---

As you need context items to be dynamic, you will have to do these in the `MouseDown` event aswell.

In order to add an item properly you still need a normal click event:

```
context_sub.Items.Add("Name of Item", Nothing, AddressOf item_Click)
```

Then add a `Sub` like this:

```
Private Sub item_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'Add any logic here, you can still use the dgv_sub.SelectedRows here
End Sub
```

Ideally you create a different `Sub` for every context menu item you need to add

Comment: Thanks Keith, this is very wide answer. Still... how would I know under item_Click which menuitem invokes it? This is important part of question.

Comment: You can use the sender parameter. So if you cast `sender` to `ToolStripMenuItem` you would know exactly who called it: `Dim menu as ToolStripMenuItem = Ctype(sender,ToolStripMenuItem)`

Comment: Thanks again. This is very useful. I get it to work with help of your answer.